# Unable to generate a proper allure report using TestNG + Maven suite

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, allure

**Setup:**

- Eclipse IDE
- Mac OS (El Capitan)/Windows 8.1
- Project type - Java + TestNG but converted to Maven
- Maven dependencies for Selenium, TestNG, Allure-TestNG adapters, AspectJ etc have been added to the POM file

**Project folder structure:**

MyProject_V1
    --src
    --src > config
    --src > web
    --src > web > SampleTest_testng.java
MyProject_V1 image: [my project file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThmcG.png)

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

SampleTest.java:

```
@Title("Customer Service Header Test")
public class SampleTest_testng {
static WebDriver wd;
static ReusableMethods global_method = new ReusableMethods();

@Stories("Customer Service")
@BeforeClass
public void openBrowser() {
    wd = new FirefoxDriver();
}

@Test
public void getUrl() {
    wd.get("http://www.mudah.my/support.htm?ca=9_s");
    wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Step("Find the total number of H4 elements")
private void findElementH4() {
    int total_css = wd.findElements(By.cssSelector("h4")).size();
    System.out.println(total_css + "\n");
}

@Step("Get the text for the first H4 element")
private void findFirstH4Element() {
            System.out.println(wd.findElements(By.cssSelector("h4")).get(0).getText());
}

@Step("Get the text for the second H4 element")
private void findSecondH4Element() {
    System.out.println(wd.findElements(By.cssSelector("h4")).get(1).getText());
}

@Step("Get the text for the third H4 element")
private void findThirdH4Element() {
    System.out.println(wd.findElements(By.cssSelector("h4")).get(3).getText());
}

@AfterClass
public void closeBrowser(){
    wd.close();
}
```

}

**Issues:**

1. When I go to terminal to run the test: mvn clean test site, the test will only run @Test

**Remarks:**

- If I don't follow this structure and have all my tests in chunks of @Tests, running mvn:allure-report will give me a breakdown of the tests that have succeeded running.
- on Windows machine, if any of the imports for allure are detected, I won't be able to drill through any of the allure report segments like xUnit, Behaviours or Graphs
- I can only open the index.html on Firefox but not Google Chrome
- I get an error when I do mvn site:

  `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site     (default-site) on project SeleniumAutomationSuite_V3: failed to get report for ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-maven-plugin: Plugin ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-maven-plugin:1.4.22 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-maven-plugin:jar:1.4.22 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]`

Does anyone know what may be the problem? Is it my project structure? I'm new to Maven and am trying to use it to manage my dependencies. I tried looking around for more info relating to the error hoping that it may shed some light on why allure is not running at all.

Thanks!

Comment: You should follow the [default folder layout of Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) otherwise this makes your life harder. The Error message states that you are behind a corporate firewall / proxy which is not correctly configured in Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Your `allure-maven-plugin` version is wrong. There is no `ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-maven-plugin:1.4.22` available.

The latest version of Allure Maven Plugin is `2.5`.

Also you need to run `test` and `site` goals separately to generate the report if some tests are failed (or use `testFailureIgnore` flag in surefire plugin)

To view the report in Chrome you need to use web server due to security issues. For more details see [FAQ](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure1/wiki/FAQ-and-Troubleshooting#i-see-nothing-when-opening-the-report-page-in-my-browser--access-denied-message).